# Merge two DataFrames based on a string aggregated column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have the below DF that contains

| Lookup | Definition |
| --- | --- |
| A | Apple |
| B | Banana |
| C | Carrot |

I have another DF2:

| SNo | Lookup Values |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | `['A', 'B']` |
| 2 | `['A', 'C']` |
| 3 | `['B', 'C']` |

**Note**: "Lookup Values" column is a list of strings

What is the most simple way of performing the JOIN to get the below:

| SNo | Lookup Values | Lookup Definitions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A, B | Apple, Banana |
| 2 | A, C | Apple, Carrot |
| 3 | B, C | Banana, Carrot |

Comment: are the `Lookup Values` list of strings?

Comment: Yes, the field is a list of strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try explode, merge, then groupby:

```
(df2.explode('Lookup Values')
    .merge(df1, left_on='Lookup Values', right_on='Lookup', how='left')
    .groupby('SNo', as_index=False)
    .agg({'Lookup':','.join, 'Definition':','.join})
)
```

Output:

```
   SNo Lookup     Definition
0    1    A,B   Apple,Banana
1    2    B,C  Banana,Carrot
2    3    C,A   Carrot,Apple
```

Comment: I get the error `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found`. Is this because I could have None/NaN in the list? If so, any way to skip those?

Comment: @Parsh, update your input sample with a more representative values (including `NaN/None` if therea re such)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way with using `map()`

```
(df2.explode('Lookup Values')
.dropna()
.assign(**{'Lookup Definitions':lambda x: x['Lookup Values'].map(dict(df.to_records(index = False)))})
.groupby('SNo')
.agg(', '.join)
.reset_index())
```

Output:

```
   SNo Lookup Values Lookup Definitions
0    1          A, B      Apple, Banana
1    2          A, C      Apple, Carrot
2    3          B, C     Banana, Carrot
```

Comment: Fancy upacking there!

Answer (score 3):

1. `explode` the list columns
2. `merge` to get the definitions
3. `groupby` and `agg` as needed

```
>>> df2.explode("Lookup Values").merge(df, left_on="Lookup Values", right_on="Lookup").groupby("SNo")[["Lookup Values", "Definition"]].agg(", ".join)

    Lookup Values      Definition
SNo                              
1            A, B   Apple, Banana
2            A, C   Apple, Carrot
3            B, C  Banana, Carrot
```

Comment: I get the error `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found`. Is this because I could have None/NaN in the list? If so, any way to skip those?

Comment: Which columns have `Nan`? If you want to ignore those, you can first use `df2 = df2.dropna()` before using the above.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution:

```py
df2["Lookup Definitions"] = df2["Lookup Values"].apply(
    lambda x, m=df1.set_index("Lookup")["Definition"].to_dict(): ", ".join(
        m[v] for v in x if v in m
    )
)
print(df2)
```

Prints:

```
   SNo Lookup Values Lookup Definitions
0    1        [A, B]      Apple, Banana
1    2        [A, C]      Apple, Carrot
2    3        [B, C]     Banana, Carrot
```